# Third eigenvalue of Lorentz equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I was reading and working on the Strogatz's book on nonlinear dynamics and chaos on my own. I was trying to solve problem 9.2.1. The thing is that, I do not understand how can I solve part c) of that problem. I've seen in the internet that they find the third eigenvalue saying that is is well known that the sum of the three eigenvalues must give a certain quantity. Since they know two of the eigenvalues, they solve for the other. It strikes me how can they know what does the sum of the three values give.

Please, find attached the book with the problem on page 342.
http://arslanranjha.weebly.com/uploads/4/8/9/3/4893701/nonlinear-dynamics-and-chaos-strogatz.pdf

Comment: Is this book copy permitted to be uploaded on the internet for free?

Comment: I do not know. I did not uploaded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), you can find the third eigenvalue from the first two eigenvalues and the coefficient at $\lambda^2$ in the polynom of the third degree for the eigenvalues.